# Vim also deletes the line under the selected region -- why?

Tags: visual-mode

To delete multiple lines, I highlight a line with <kbd>Shift v</kbd>. And then go down a few lines and press <kbd>d</kbd>.

When I do this, Vim deletes the selected lines and the line directly below it.

I am not sure what has created this behavior?

Comment: I can't reproduce the behavior. In particular `<S-v>d` deletes only the current line. Is it different for you?

Comment: Do you still have that problem without your config? `$ vim -Nu NONE`.

Comment: I try this in NeoVim AND Vim. But everything works fine. 10 Lines (Line 1, Line 2, Line 3, ...) I highlight with Line 2, 3 and 4 with: ggjVjj
Then I delete this with: d The Result:
Line 1
Line 5
Line 6
... I try also: - Delete with D (shift d) - Delete with :d - Delete with :2,4d - Visual Studio Code VIM-Extension Everything works fine. Which Version of VIM you use?
My Versions: NVIM v0.9.0 and VIM 9.0.1313

Comment: It seems to work fine with I do `vim -Nu NONE`. I believe it might be one of my auto commands. I will test this today and feedback what created this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After experimenting with my .vimrc, it was this line:

`vnoremap jk <esc>`

When I pressed <kbd>j</kbd> in visual mode, it didn't visibally go down because it was waiting for the <kbd>k</kbd>.